# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

**I am trying to create new Empty project in Android Studio and trying to run it, build getting failed every time. Showing me some build failed error.**

Please look into the below Screenshot as reference: [image]

**Software Version:**

1. Android Studio - 2021.2.1
2. JDK - 18.0.1
3. OS - Windows 11 Pro

**Tried:**

- Changed JDK versions : 18, 17, 15, 11.
- Checked every time JAVA_HOME and Path in System variables.
- Lots of solutions tried available in the internet.
- Changed gradle version from 7.3.3 to 7.1 or 7.0 or 6.8 in gradle-wripper.properties
  [image]

None of the above solution worked for me.
Please help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It assumes like the Android Studio can't  download the gradle, check your internet connection, or maybe you have installed a certification or a proxy or a vpn that block the connexion of Android Studio. I had the same problem with a certification, when i removed it, everything was well.

Comment: Ok  thanks for idea. Where can I check those certificates that I can remove?